# Защита игры от взлома

Tags: разработка-игр, клиент-сервер, защита

Никогда не разрабатывал игры, интересует такой вопрос, допустим есть клиент игры в котором есть персонаж "лучник" который стреляет со скоростью 1 выстрел в 1 секунду, если с помощью программы(например hlapex) поймать пакет который отвечает за выстрел, и отсылать его каждые 0.1 то лучник получается будет делать 10 выстрелов в 1 секунду? То есть на сервере нужно проверять когда был последний выстрел и если следующий выстрел слишком быстро произошел, то блокировать этот выстрел? Или я что-то не понимаю и выстрелы не отправляются? Вообщем может кто-то объяснить?

Comment: В клиент-серверных приложениях по возможности все, что касается обработки данных игры, должен обрабатывать сервер. Клиент должен отвечать только за графический вывод и взаимодействие с пользователем. Поэтому помимо блокировки отправки на клиенте обязательна проверка таймера на сервере.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все верно. Учитывай время между запросами. Блокируй если "выстрелы" приходят при меньшем таймауте чем разрешено.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я знаю, хорошей практикой считается не отправка на сервер пакета с действием как например "Выстрел", а отправка пакета "Начал стрельбу" по нажатию клавиши и "Закончил стрельбу" по отпусканию клавиши. 
Скорость атаки, количество выстрелов и всё остальное при этом будет считаться на сервере, пока идёт стрельба. 
Как минимум такой подход защитит от ситуации, описанной в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Вот это решение, думается мне, более рационально. Ибо в случае, когда сервер ловит по одному обращению в секунду, можно легко заDDoSить свой же сервер, если пользователей окажется достаточно.

Частые обращения от одного клиента можно отбрасывать на уровне прокси. При наличии.